# How does operator<< overloading work?

Tags: c++

Given a class:

```
struct employee {
    string name;
    string ID;
    string phone;
    string department;
};
```

How does the following function work?

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, employee &o)
{
 s << o.name << endl;
 s << "Emp#: " << o.ID << endl;
 s << "Dept: " << o.department << endl;
 s << "Phone: " << o.phone << endl;

 return s;
}
```

`cout << e;` produces formatted output for a given `employee e`.

Example output:

```
Alex Johnson
Emp#: 5719
Dept: Repair
Phone: 555-0174
```

I can't understand how the ostream function works. How does it get the parameter "ostream &s"?How does it overload the "<<" operator and how does the << operator work? How can it be used to write all of the information about an employee? Can someone please answer these questions in the layman's terms?

Comment: Overloaded operators are mostly just syntactic sugar for a function call, The expression `cout << *itr` for instance is equivalent to saying `operator<<(cout, *itr)`, and in fact using this syntax works exactly the same way.

Comment: You are beter off learning these things from a book.

Comment: As a side note: The signature of the output operator overload should be `ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, const employee &o)` and all the getter functions should be `const` as well, since there's no change in the `Employee` instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called overload resolution.
You've written `cout << *itr`.
Compiler takes it as `operator<<(cout, *itr);`, where `cout` is an instance of `ostream` and `*itr` is an instance of employee.
You've defined function `void operator<<(ostream&, employee&);` which match most closely to your call.
So the call gets translated with `cout` for `s` and `*itr` for `o`

Answer (score 1):

Given an `employee e;`.
the following code: 
`cout << e;`

will call your **overloaded** function and pass references to `cout` and `e`.

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, const employee &o)
{
    // print the name of the employee e to cout 
    // (for our example parameters)
    s << o.name << endl; 

    // ...

    // return the stream itself, so multiple << can be chained 
    return s;
}
```

*Sidenote*: the reference to the `employee` should be const, since we do not change it, as pointed out by πάντα ῥεῖ